Migration from org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.swagger -> org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.openapi
After up Spring Boot to version 3 I try to migrate from Swagger to OpenAPI.
Project depends on Apache CXF.
How can I rewrite the swagger configuration?
It was before OpenApi:
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
@Bean
    public Swagger2Feature swagger2Feature() {
        Swagger2Feature swagger = new Swagger2Feature();
        swagger.setVersion(*version*);
        swagger.setBasePath(*basePath*);
        swagger.setPrettyPrint(true);
        swagger.setSchemes(new String[]{"https", "http"});
        swagger.setContact(*contact*);
        swagger.setDescription(*description*);
        swagger.setTitle(*title*);
        swagger.setSupportSwaggerUi(true);
        swagger.setHost(*host*);
        return swagger;
    }
}

I try just replace Swagger2Feature to OpenApiFeature but swagger ui does not open after it.
@Bean
    public OpenApiFeature openApiFeature() {
        OpenApiFeature openApi = new OpenApiFeature();
        openApi.setVersion(*version*);
        openApi.setPrettyPrint(true);
        openApi.setContactEmail(*email*);
        openApi.setDescription(*description*);
        openApi.setTitle(*title*);
        openApi.setSupportSwaggerUi(true);
        openApi.setSwaggerUiConfig(
            new SwaggerUiConfig()
                .url("/openapi.json"));
        return openApi;
    }


Solution: just replace @Path annotation from interface to impl.
Jaxrs with openapi dont see controller if @Path annotation not on class.
Example:
Will not work:
    @Path(/some)
    interface ExampleController{}
    class ExampleControllerImpl implements ExampleController{}

should work:
    interface ExampleController{}
    @Path(/some)
    class ExampleControllerImpl implements ExampleController{}

